# What are the cases where the verb 'see' can be used as present participle?

Tags: grammar

The following are found as to the verb 'see' in Oxford Learner's Dictionaries:

1. [transitive, intransitive] (**not used in the progressive tenses**)
   to become aware of somebody/something by using your eyes
2. [transitive] (**not usually used in the progressive tenses**)
   to watch a game, television programme, performance, etc.

But, I came across 'seeing' meaning the above in the following sentences from New York Times. I wondered how the seeing's are justified grammatically.

- In March 2019, scientists studying whales near Southwestern Australia stumbled upon a supersize spectacle that few had seen before — a pod of orcas viciously attacking a blue whale.
  “Upon approach, we were astounded at what we were ***seeing***,” said Rebecca Wellard, the founder and lead researcher at Project ORCA, who was among the researchers who witnessed the 2019 attack. “When you come across a unique event like this, I think it takes a while to process just what you are ***seeing***.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not uses as a participle: they are uses of so-called continuous tenses.

The note on the definition is overstating the case: *see* is not **usually** used in continuous tenses, but it can be, to emphasise the immediate nature of the seeing.

I usually use an example from narration, something like "I'm watching the video. I'm seeing him open the door and walk along the passage."

In both your examples a simple tense would be possible, but the continuous tense evokes an image of watching as the event proceeded, becoming more surprised.